# Not able to open gsp files in STS

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When i try to open .gsp files in sts it gives me error "could not open the editor could not be intitialized". and "Unable to create editor ID com.springsource.sts.grails.editor.gsp.editor: Editor could not be initialized."how to resolve this

Comment: I would be tempted to install a fresh STS instance, install Grails Support, and try to re-open my application there.

Comment: i found a plugin missing so installed that ,now its working fine